# Recover terminal commands after macOS Catalina install switches from bash to zsh

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, conda, zsh

I recently updated my Macbook to macOS Catalina. Terminal now runs with `zsh` instead of `bash`, and many familiar commands no longer work. For example:

```
conda list
zsh: command not found: conda
```

First I tried the [change shell](http://t.ly/Odl7e) approach:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
Changing shell for michaelboles.
```

No error raised, and looking in "Users and Groups" confirms that `Login shell: /bin/bash`. I can also try the same `chsh` command again, and it says `chsh: no changes made`, suggesting the first change was successful.

But when I try again:

```
conda list
zsh: command not found: conda
```

So I looked into an alternative -- [install bash with brew](http://t.ly/PGVwM). Following this, I tried:

```
brew install bash
zsh: command not found: brew
```

Even when I'm using a `bash` shell, it's raising `zsh` errors!

Please help me change it back to the old, functioning `bash` Terminal I've been using, or get `zsh` to work as `bash` did for me earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to copy some text from my `~/.bash_profile` to `~/.zshrc` as described [here](http://t.ly/9qdjY). Now everything works again!

Comment: If it's in `.bash_profile`, I would copy it to `.zprofile` instead.

Comment: @MichaelBoles : Depends on what is your goal. From the title of your post, I thought that you would like to continue using bash, and with your approach, you are still using zsh.This is not wrong (for instance I prefer zsh over bash and already used zsh on older MacOS versions), but you need to make up your mind, what you want. In particular if you continue to use bash for scripting, but zsh interactively, it might get confusing when things work differently in the script and on the command line.

Comment: You're right -- I was asking how to change back to ```bash```, but my proposed solution is simply recovering the functionality of my old ```bash``` terminal commands while staying with ```zsh```. Thanks for pointing this out. I've changed the title of my question to reflect this.